# HTML code is showing in .PHP page

Tags: php, html, ipv6

i'm writing my first page with PHP and HTML mixed.
This page shows the visitor's ip address (ipv4 or ipv6). The PHP script is working fine, but the HTML code is showing as text instead of rendering.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<title>mioipv6.it</title>
<body>
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
if ( array_key_exists('addr', $_GET) )
$ip = $_GET['addr'];
else
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$v6 = preg_match("/^[0-9a-f]{1,4}:([0-9a-f]{0,4}:){1,6}[0-9a-f]{1,4}$/", $ip);
$v4 = preg_match("/^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$/", $ip);
if ( $v6 != 0 )
$type = "IPv6";
elseif ( $v4 != 0 )
$type = "IPv4";
else
$type = "unknown";
echo json_encode(array("Il tuo indirizzo" => $ip, "Tipo" => $type));
?> 
<a href='http://ipv6-test.com/validate.php?url=referer'><img src='http://ipv6-test.com/button-ipv6-small.png' alt='ipv6 ready' title='ipv6 ready' border='0' /></a>
</body>
</html>
```

you can see the page here: www.mioipv6.it

Comment: Are you running a web server? Or are you just opening it in the browser directly?

Comment: webserver on OVH, you can see the page here: www.mioipv6.it

Comment: Line 6 of your code wont work - you can't make `header()` calls after you've sent any output to the browser.

Comment: I'm saddened by the lack of indentation here...

Comment: @AlessandroRomboni for future reference, it's often a good idea to develop with error reporting set to display everything so these kinds of errors will show (something like this: https://eval.in/244878)

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Comment: You should explain why this would help, rather than just stating it.  That way, the person posting the question (and others) can learn from your answer rather than blindly following advice.